# Regex in grunt-version

Tags: regex, wordpress, gruntjs, versioning

I'm trying to use the [`grunt-version`](https://github.com/kswedberg/grunt-version) to bump the version of my PHP WordPress Plugin project. For a long time I tried and tried, but failed.

In my plugin file `example.php` I have a PHP variable denoting the project version:

```
public $version = '0.3.4';
```

I need to match the string so that I can bump the version here too.

I tried:

```
prefix: 'public\s\$version\s='
```

As of regex101.com it matches the string completely. The version number portion is dealt with the grunt plugin completely.

But the `grunt version::patch` says:

> Pattern not found in file
>   Path: example.php
>   Pattern: `/(publics$versions=s)([0-9a-zA-Z\-_\+\.]+)/g`

So I modified the pattern to:

```
prefix: 'public/\s\$version/\s=/\s'
```

But it's not matching:

> Pattern: `/(public\/s$version\/s=\/s)([0-9a-zA-Z\-_\+\.]+)/g`

Nonetheless, the following pattern is working fine in the same file:

```
prefix: 'Version:\\s+'
```

And bumping version nicely in plugin header:

> Version:           0.3.4

So I tried:

```
prefix: 'public \$version =\\s+'
```

But no luck:

> Pattern: `/(public $version =\s+)([0-9a-zA-Z\-_\+\.]+)/g`

FYI, my Gruntfile declaration is like below:

```
version: {
    pluginVersion: {
        options: {
            prefix: 'Version:\\s+'
        },
        src: [
            'example.php'
        ]
    },
    pluginVariable: {
        options: {
            prefix: 'public \$version =\\s+'
        },
        src: [
            'example.php'
        ]
    },
    packageJson: {
        src: [
            'package.json'
        ]
    }
},
```

### Edit

And needless to say the default pattern (`'[^\\-]version[\'"]?\\s*[:=]\\s*[\'"]'`) is changing some unwanted versions too. Like:

> public $wp_version = '0.3.0';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regular expression to match it: `public\s?\$version\s?=\s?'`

(`public\\s+\\$version\\s+=\\s+\'` escaped)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o9RzYD/1)

Comment: No, the version portion is dealt with the grunt-version plugin. Need to match the `public $version = ` portion of my string

Comment: Oops ! fixed ;)

Comment: The plugin translated your pattern into: `Pattern: /(publics?$versions?=s?)([0-9a-zA-Z\-_\+\.]+)/g`. So, I escaped slashes `public/\s?\$version/\s?=/\s?`, but still no luck. `Pattern: /(public\/s?$version\/s?=\/s?)([0-9a-zA-Z\-_\+\.]+)/g` - _Pattern not found in file_

Comment: You need to escape slashes like this \\ not like this /\

Comment: Changed into: `public\\s?\$version\\s?=\\s?`, but no luck. The plugin translated to: `Pattern: /(public\s?$version\s?=\s?)([0-9a-zA-Z\-_\+\.]+)/g`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141779/discussion-between-mayeenul-islam-and-stej4n).

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to use this with the style.css and/or plugin files:

```
version: {
   project: {
     options: {
       release: 'patch',
       prefix: '\\s*([^\\w][\'"]?[v|V]{1}ersion[\'"]?\\s*[:=]\\s*[\'"]?)'
     },
     src: ['package.json', 'style.css']
   }
}
```

make sure you register your task (as per docs)

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-version');
```

then you can run the task as such

```
grunt version
```